# Combine Multiple Categories Into One URL Slug

Tags: url-rewriting, categories, permalinks

I have a Wordpress website with 20+ categories. To make it easier to navigate I want to decrease the categories, but at the same time keep the original categories. In other words I want to be able to query multiple categories with a category group or a virtual slug.

Example categories:

```
/category/apples/
/category/pears/
/category/bananas/
```

I want to be able to query all three of them with a unique url slug:

```
/category/fruit/
```

But like I said, it should still be possible to go to i.e. **/category/bananas/**

I know it's possible to query multiple categories the way I want to using **/category/apples,bananas,pears/** but it's not a elegant solution.

Is it possible to do this virtual grouping with a plugin or even using a rewrite?

Tips and recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do not want to use subcategories for this. Any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Bump, I am sure there is someone out there who knows what I want to do without using parent categories.

Answer (score 4):

You could override your query with `pre_get_posts` in `functions.php`:

```
function add_all_fruits_to_category($query) {
    $catnames = $query->get('category_name');
    if ($catnames == 'fruits') {
        $query->set('category_name', $catnames . ',bananas,apples,pears');
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'add_all_fruits_to_category');
```

Comment: Thanks Virgil! This is what I wanted from the getko! It works very well, except that I get a couple of warning messages:

Warning: rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string,    object given in wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1381

Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/frontend/class-frontend.php on line 735.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I got the same problem today, but only as I tried to set category_name to '' and filter with cat. I couldn't solve it by any other means than sticking with category_name.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you here? What did you change exactly?

Comment: Bump, anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't WordPress's built-in sub-categories functionality solve this problem?

```
 + fruit
  + bananas
  + apples
  + pears
```

you would get all of fruit through

```
/categories/fruit
```

but also specific categories through

```
/categories/fruit/bananas
```

to add a sub-category, just choose `fruit` as the parent category for each child.

Comment: I do not want to use any subcategories. This defeats the purpose of keeping the original categories and permalinks. I also like to keep it this way because of SEO reasons.

Comment: Hmm. Would it then not be simpler to try and hide bananas, apples, and pears from the navigation, but keep them as categories? That might be less work than finding a plugin that rewrites the handling of categories fundamentally

Comment: What I want is to be able to place a link to these virtual categories in my navigation and display posts attached to these categories.

Comment: @Chris as said, it would probably be easier to have `fruit` as a separate (but real) category in your category tree, alongside bananas, apples, and pears, but *hiding those in the menu.* So an apple entry is both in the /apple and the /fruit category, but only the /fruit category is visible in the menu. (But /apple still works for SEO). Is that a workable option? I'm not aware of a plugin that does *exactly* what you want (although there may be one)

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but that would require to create new parent categories for the navigation and then move the 20+ categories into those as child categories. I want to still be able to use all my inlinks to my pages and I believe regrouping the categories this way will create alot of 404 pages, true?

Comment: @Chris true, but what I suggest in the comment above is different from what I suggest in the answer (which I agree is useless to you in light of what you said, just keeping it around so we can finish this discussion)

Comment: So, let me get this straight. What you are suggesting would create the following permalink structure: /category/fruit/ & /category/fruit/bananas/ and for the post it self: /fruit/bananas/postname?

Comment: @Chris no, the new suggestion (in the comments above, not in the answer) is: `/category/fruit` **and** `/category/bananas` and for the post.. hadn't thought about that part yet; in the navigation, show `/category/fruit` but hide `/category/bananas` because your end goal is to have less categories in the nav. (Correct?) Hiding categories from the nav is possible using an array IIRC when calling `show_categories`, so there might not even be a need for a plugin

Comment: So to make that work I would have to link each post to two categories. In this case both bananas and fruit. Otherwise I don't see how the permalink structure could end up like you are suggesting. Either way it screws with my permalink structure and I do not want to create rewrite rules to redirect to the new scheme.

Comment: @Chris yup, you'd have to link it to two categories. The two categories don't have anything to do with each other. I don't think it'll require you to change your permalink structure though? Except if you have a `/categoryname/postname` scheme running, I don't know how that would react to a post having two categories.

Comment: I do have a /categoryname/postname/ scheme running, so if I use childcategories, those permalinks would change. I guess a WP rewrite is the best solution here in the end. Anyone know of a good plugin to handle this with ease?

Comment: +1. Hierarchical categories solves *exactly* the problem the OP proposes. This is the correct solution.

Comment: Hierarchical categories solves the problem with hierarchy. But it does not solve my main issue, I want to be able to keep my original permalink structure.

Creating parent categories and moving my existing categories into them changes all my category links which among other things creates SEO problems for me (I also display top posts based on Google Analytics statistics).

I do not want to go this route, that's why I was asking about a plugin that can create a virtual category container or a rewrite to solve it.