# Identical custom taxonomy slugs for same hierarchical children

Tags: functions, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, slug, hierarchical

I have a custom taxonomy (editions) and would like to have a year / month hierarchy in the taxonomy reflected in the URL structure.

```
/editions/2016/december
/editions/2017/december
/editions/2018/december
```

WordPress doesn't seem to allow me to create this on the admin side. Is this possible?

For reference, here is my custom taxonomy setup inside of my `functions.php`:

```
/* Editions Function */
function aa_editions_tax() {
  register_taxonomy( 'editions', 'page', array(
    'labels' => array(
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Edition',
      'all_items' => 'All Editions',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Edition',
      'menu_name' => 'Editions',
      'name' => 'Editions',
      'new_item' => 'New Edition',
      'not_found' => 'No Editions Found',
      'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Editions Found in Trash',
      'parent' => 'Parent of Edition',
      'search_items' => 'Search Editions',
      'singular_name' => 'Edition',
      'view_item' => 'View Edition'
    ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'hierarchical' => true
        ),
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_ui' => true
  ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'aa_editions_tax' );
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Since you can only have unique term slugs in a taxonomy, you should go for a "mixed taxonomy term" url setup.

You can check [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71630/combine-multiple-categories-into-one-url-slug), or this [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31738/how-do-i-append-multiple-taxonomies-to-the-url) that involve creating your own [add_rewrite_rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

Comment: Thanks J. This is exactly what I did but when you create the identical children, `December` for example, WordPress will not give those children the same slug. They get slugs like `december-2017` and `december-2018`, etc. Any idea how to get that to happen?

Comment: Another method is to just do a combination of month and year into the same top-level category `2016-January` - it wouldn't be the end of the world.

Comment: true @staypuftman. in the same taxonomy you can only have unique slugs. you'll have to go for a mixed taxonomy-term, solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info - seems crazy you can't do this. Are we missing something in the codex?

Comment: @staypuftman well it makes sense that an url is univocal and unambiguous. however I think that a better term relationship, db-wise, would help.

Comment: Right, it's a fundamental data architecture problem. I don't think it can be solved without some rewrite rules at the server level. Just isn't worth it for this use case. Thanks for your input, appreciated.

Comment: Here in 2021, and can confirm that this still not possible.